# Angular: unable to catch message of 404 API through service

Tags: angular

I want to show message returned by the API which status is 404 as below:

```
{message: "Email Address does not exists", status: 404, data: null}
```

This API is generated in SpringBoot language.

I'm calling the API in Angular 8 through a `service.ts` file:

```
forgotPwd(value, bearer) {
  return this.http.put(this.rootUrl + 'api/user/forgot_password', value,  {headers: new HttpHeaders({  Authorization: 'Bearer ' + bearer, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'})});
}
```

And in the `component.ts` file, I want to handle the situation like:

```
this.commService.forgotPwd(this.submissionArray, this.userToken).subscribe((data: any) => {
  this.rawData = data;
  const result = this.rawData;
  if (result.status !== 200) {
    console.log(result.message);
  } else {
    console.log(result.message);
  }
});
```

However, I did not see anything in the console. How can handle 404 / 400 request in Angular and can throw corresponding message in the component file as mentioned above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the http errors will be available in the error callback, for example

```
this.service.getData()
    .subscribe(
      (data) => {}, // success path
      (error: HttpErrorResponse)=> {} // error path
    );
```

In the error, you will get the status and message.

So for your case,

```
this.commService.forgotPwd(this.submissionArray, this.userToken)
.subscribe((data: any) => {
  this.rawData = data;
  const result = this.rawData;
    console.log(result.message);
}, error => {
   console.log('handle error');
});
```

Note: The above scenario works, when the Rest API returns 4XX or 5XX as response status.